# Rspec + Spork ошибки запуска тестов

Tags: ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails

Добрый день!

При запуске Rspec тестов с опцией --drb (spork в это время уже работает) возникают ошибки

- OC: Windows 7
- ruby -v : ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08) [i386-mingw32]
- rails -v : 4.1.1
- Gemfile

  ```
  group :test do
    gem 'capybara'
    gem 'shoulda-matchers'
    gem 'rspec-rails'
    gem 'spork-rails'
    gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.0'
  end
  ```

Текст ошибки
    >rspec . --drb
    (druby://192.168.100.2:52095) C:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/spork-1.0.
    0rc4-x86-mingw32/lib/spork/test_framework/rspec.rb:11:in `run_tests': uninitiali
    zed constant RSpec::Core::CommandLine (NameError)
        from (druby://192.168.100.2:52095) C:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/ge
    ms/spork-1.0.0rc4-x86-mingw32/lib/spork/run_strategy/magazine/magazine_slave.rb:
    22:in`run'
        from (druby://192.168.100.2:52095) C:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/drb/drb
    .rb:1588:in `perform_without_block'
        from (druby://192.168.100.2:52095) C:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/drb/drb
    .rb:1548:in`perform'
        from (druby://192.168.100.2:52095) C:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/drb/drb
    .rb:1626:in `block (2 levels) in main_loop'
        from (druby://192.168.100.2:52095) C:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/drb/drb
    .rb:1622:in`loop'
        from (druby://192.168.100.2:52095) C:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/drb/drb
    .rb:1622:in `block in main_loop'
        from (druby://127.0.0.1:8989) C:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sp
    ork-1.0.0rc4-x86-mingw32/lib/spork/run_strategy/magazine.rb:99:in`run'
        from (druby://127.0.0.1:8989) C:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sp
    ork-1.0.0rc4-x86-mingw32/lib/spork/server.rb:49:in `run'
        from (druby://127.0.0.1:8989) C:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/drb/drb.rb:1
    588:in`perform_without_block'
        from (druby://127.0.0.1:8989) C:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/drb/drb.rb:1
    548:in `perform'
        from (druby://127.0.0.1:8989) C:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/drb/drb.rb:1
    626:in`block (2 levels) in main_loop'
        from (druby://127.0.0.1:8989) C:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/drb/drb.rb:1
    622:in `loop'
        from (druby://127.0.0.1:8989) C:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/drb/drb.rb:1
    622:in`block in main_loop'
        from C:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/
    core/drb.rb:23:in `run'
        from C:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/
    core/runner.rb:64:in`run'
        from C:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/
    core/runner.rb:38:in `invoke'
        from C:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/exe/rspec:
    4:in`<top (required)>'
        from C:/row/Ruby200/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
        from C:/row/Ruby200/bin/rspec:23:in`<main>'

При запуске тестов без --drb все проходит без ошибок

Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто знает как исправить
Заранее благодарен!

P.S.: Почему-то блок кода в посте не отображается. Извиняюсь если трудно читать

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в этом RSpec::Core::CommandLine (NameError). В rspec 3 это все изменили https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/Changelog.md

Решить можно, изменив исходники спорка

https://github.com/manafire/spork/commit/38c79dcedb246daacbadb9f18d09f50cc837de51#diff-937afaa19ccfee172d722a05112a7c6fL6